# I have an index of variables. I need to find which ones are linked to a value of 1 and print their location in the list

Tags: python

```
Apples = 1
Oranges = 0
Bananas = 1
Grapes = 0

list1 = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Grapes"]
```

So in this example the locations should be 0 and 2.

Comment: `Apples` and `"Apples"` are totally different objects. If you are thinking of accessing `Apples` based on the string `"Apples"`, it is not recommended. You can instead use a dict.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Maxwell D. Dorliea  Maybe Im not asking my question correctly.  I basically just want to create an index of variables and then lookup those variables position in the list if variables linked value equals a number.

Comment: Why don't you used python dictionary or is it a requirement to used list?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Apples = 1
Oranges = 0
Bananas = 1
Grapes = 0

list1 = [Apples, Oranges, Bananas, Grapes]
y = len(list1)

for x in range(0,y):
    if list1[x] == 1:
        print (x)
```